# main.exe - Entry Point Not Found Error (C++)

Tags: c++, compilation, shared-ptr

New to C++, might be simple. This is the implementation of someone else's code.

I have a file Main.cpp that initializes an instance of the class hittable_list.h. The code for hittable_list.h is as follows:

```
#ifndef HITTABLE_LIST_H
#define HITTABLE_LIST_H

#include "hittable.h"

#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using std::shared_ptr;
using std::make_shared;

class hittable_list : public hittable {
    public:
        hittable_list() {}
        hittable_list(shared_ptr<hittable> object) { add(object); }

        void clear() { objects.clear(); }
        void add(shared_ptr<hittable> object) { objects.push_back(object); }

        virtual bool hit(const ray& r, double tmin, double tmax, hit_record& rec) const;

    public:
        std::vector<shared_ptr<hittable>> objects;
};

bool hittable_list::hit(const ray& r, double tmin, double tmax, hit_record& rec) const {
    hit_record temp_rec;
    bool hit_anything = false;
    auto closest_so_far = tmax;

    for (const auto& object : objects) {
        if (object->hit(r, tmin, closest_so_far, temp_rec)) {
            hit_anything = true;
            closest_so_far = temp_rec.t;
            rec = temp_rec;
        }
    }

    return hit_anything;
}

#endif
```

I complile (on Windows 10) from the command prompt with **g++ Main.cpp -o main.exe**. On running main.exe, I get the error:

> main.exe - Entry Point Not Found:
>   The procedure entry point __gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link link library [path to main.exe].

Just from commenting out stuff I know the issue is with the line

```
std::vector<shared_ptr<hittable>> objects;
```

but I am not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: Recommend showing that main.cpp has a `main` function, but last time I saw that message, I was missing the libstdc++ dll.

Comment: @user4581301 How do I get this? I forgot to mention that Main.cpp will build from Visual Studio but not from the command prompt.

Comment: In the same folder as the g++ compiler you should find a whole raft of DLLs. If you can build with `g++ Main.cpp -o main.exe`, presumably this folder is in the system path and the system should be able to find the DLLs. See what happens if you force static linking with  `g++ -static Main.cpp -o main.exe`

Comment: @user4581301 That worked. Thanks so much.

Comment: What that did was build the Standard library into the executable. It's going to be bigger now, probably much bigger, but you can move the program around easier because you don't have to bundle the DLLs with it when you share it with someone.